# Yet another eclipse+TFS .tpignore issue

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse is not respecting the ignore rules in .tpignore and in ignored ressources. I've googled this issue and found many frustrated users having the same problem. One work around was to undo pending changes reapply changes and check in, which did not solve my issue. Has anyone managed to solve this issue? Also, sometimes I get "add" under change for files, that do not even exist in my project...

EDIT: The issue only occurs on my PC. My co-workers never had this problem

Example:

among the many rules .tpignore has, I can find:

`.*/.*_obj/`

`.*/.*_obj/.*`

When checking in, eclipse lists:

`.../MPC512X_obj/admin`

`.../MPC512X_obj/inifile`

and many others

I'm using:

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers    1.5.1.20121004-1506

Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse  11.0.0.201207250348`

Comment: Can you describe your problem more fully?  Can you provide the `.tpignore` and some examples of files that are not being ignored?  What version of the Eclipse plug-in is this?  What version of TFS?  Local workspaces or server workspaces?  This information would be helpful at a minimum.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I've just edited my question.

Comment: @H_squared Have you got any solution? I have similar issue with .recommenders and Servers folders in eclipse+TFS workspace